# What are all the hats I need to unlock Find Mii 2?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii-2

I know that to unlock Find Mii 2 you need to get all the hats from the original Find Mii.

I played through Find Mii once and the sequel didn't unlock, so I know that one playthrough doesn't give you all the hats.

What are all the hats that I need? I would like to know how close I am to unlocking Find Mii 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get all of the hats in Find Mii by completing two playthroughs.

As listed by [IGN](http://www.ign.com/cheats/games/streetpass-mii-plaza-3ds-105034), the hats from the first playthrough of Find Mii are

- Mario Hat
- Red Pikmin Hat
- Link Hat
- Samus Hat
- Kirby Hat
- Cat Hat
- Dog Hat
- Crown

And the hats from the second playthrough are

- Luigi Hat
- Toad Hat
- Bowser Hat
- Blue Pikmin Hat
- Yellow Pikmin Hat
- Metroid Hat
- Bunny Hat
- Ultimate Hat

Comment: But what are all the hats?

Comment: @AshleyNunn Sorry, I misread your question. I added the hats to my answer

Comment: Not to be annoying but can you also add the hats from the first playthrough? So it is a complete list?

Comment: @AshleyNunn I added the rest of the hats

Answer (score 4):

The hats you need to unlock Find Mii 2 in the first playthrough are

- mario hat
- red pikmin hat
- link hat
- samus hat
- kirby hat
- cat hat
- dog hat
- regal crown

on the second playthrough the hats are

- luigi hat
- bowser hat
- blue pikmin hat
- toad hat
- bunny hat
- metroid hat
- ultimate hat

but they are in random order but won't effect your progress of getting to find mii 2 but you need to playthrough find mii 1 twice

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is beat Find Mii 1 twice to get all the hats and then you should have Find Mii 2